# Unexpected behavior with MPI_Ssend and MPI_Recv

Tags: c++, mpi

I have found some unexpected behavior in MPI (using C++) in this small code example:

```
int rank, size;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

if(rank == 1) {
    int *sendDone = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));    
    *sendDone = 1;
    MPI_Ssend(sendDone,1,MPI_INT, 0, 1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
    foo();    
} else {
    int *rcvDone = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    bar();
    while(*rcvDone != 1) {
        MPI_Recv(rcvDone,1,MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    cout << *rcvDone << endl;
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

It is compiled and run with the following commands:

```
mpic++ sim.cc -o sim
mpirun -n 2 ./sim
```

The Code should be executed in the following order:

```
bar();
foo();
```

Because the Process #0 is starting to receive after the execution of **bar()**. But in reality, **foo()** is sometimes starting before **bar()** is finished. Can somebody explain that to me and give a solution to the problem?

Comment: What are `bar()` and `foo()` doing to indicate they've been called? Are they writing to `stderr`?

Comment: Please make sure to initialize `rcvDone` before you test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You haven't said how you do the check which function is called first. Cout'ing something on screen doesn't guarantee proper order of displaying messages (at least while using MPI).
2. You don't need to put MPI_Recv in loop since it is a blocking function. Its not even recommended while you didn't assign starting value to *rcvDone.
3. Its not safe to use malloc together with some MPI functions. Read "thread and interrupt safety" section on http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Ssend.html

Comment: Thanks for that. foo() and bar() are cout'ing Results and they apeared in a random order. The solution is also postet under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901226/an-atomic-call-to-cout-in-mpi